# SCSS file issue with ruby on rails and bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm currently trying to integrate a bootstrap template into an existing rails application. I changed the application.css file's name to application.css.scss, and whenever that happens I get this rails error:

Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( glyphicons-halflings.png )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
  (in /Users/alexisernst/bagels/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

I've looked at other's questions regarding this and still can't figure it out unfortunately. How can I alter my stylesheet pathways to fix this issue? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You don't - you follow the instructions in the message by adding `glyphicons-halflings.png` to your precompile array.

Comment: @sevenseacat Are you sure? I never had to add an image to the precompiler manually.

Answer (score 0):

The error is showing because of using *sprockets_better_errors* gem into Rails 4.1. See [here](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/84).

The asset pipeline errors is showing since this will occur in production mode.
You need to add the image into asset precompile list.

*config/initializers/assets.rb*

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( glyphicons-halflings.png )
```

or,

*config/application.rb*

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( glyphicons-halflings.png )
```

By default the asset pipeline will check for potential errors in development mode during runtime. You can disable this in *config/environments/development.rb*:

```
config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = false
```